# Angular5: show edit form for specific element in ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

listThirdParty component displays a list of elements using ngFor loop. 
Each element has an 'edit' button. User clicks on the button of a particular element and sees an edit form (hence all the data of that particular element is been populated into that form). EditThirdParty component displays this edit form.

User clicks on edit: variable 'thirdPartyToEdit' is assigned to the selected element and is sent to EditThirdParty component. User sees a form for that particular element. This is an expected behavior. 
But if user clicks 'edit' on another element while the first edit form is still opened, user sees two forms but with the data of the latest element user selected to edit. I understand that it is happening because I reassign 'thirdPartyToEdit' variable with the last selected item. 
I don't understand how to render an edit form for each element with correct data.

listThirdParty Component  (parent):

```
@Component({...})
export class ListThirdPartyComponent {
  public showEditForm = false;
  @Input() thirdParties = [];
  public thirdPartyToEdit = {};
  public indexThirdPartyToEdit: number;

  constructor() {}

  private editThirdParty(thirdParty, index) {
    this.thirdPartyToEdit = thirdParty
    this.indexThirdPartyToEdit = index
    this.showEditForm = true;
  }
}
```

listThirdParty.html

```
<div class="third-party-block">
   <div *ngFor="let thirdParty of thirdParties, let i = index">   
       <div class="third-party-element">
           <span (click)="editThirdParty(thirdParty, i)" (click)="thirdParty.form = true" (click)="thirdParty.hideme = false">Edit</span>            
           {{thirdParty.name}}
           <div>Role: {{thirdParty.role}}</div> 
           <div>Email: {{thirdParty.email}}</div>
           <div>Phone: {{thirdParty.phone}}</div>
           <div>Ext.: {{thirdParty.ext}}</div>                   
           <edit-third-party 
                 *ngIf="showEditForm" 
                 [hidden]="!thirdParty.form" 
                 [thirdParty]="thirdPartyToEdit> 
           </edit-third-party>
        </div>      
   </div>     
</div>
```

editThirdParty Component (Child)

```
@Component({...})
export class EditThirdPartyComponent {
 @Input() thirdParty: any;
 @Output() hideEditThirdParty = new EventEmitter<any>();

 constructor (private requestDist: RequestDistService) {}
    onSubmit(value: any) {
      this.hideEditThirdParty.emit(value)
    }
}
```

editThirdParty.html

```
<form #editThirdPartyForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(editThirdPartyForm.value)">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Third Party Name" required [ngModel]='thirdParty.name' name="name">
   </div>   
    ....other form data...            
   <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>     
</form>
```

Comment: You said user sees two forms,my question is how are you opening the child component ,is it in a dialog/separate view?Why there are two click events in span ?

Comment: Also did you once check http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1215/angular-2-crud-with-web-api-2